# Simple C calculator error

Tags: c, scanf, calculator

I was trying to make a simple c calculator because i am a newbie and thought it would be a good idea. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
 char b;
 int a,c,d;
 printf("Please enter your first number: ");
 scanf("%d",&a);
 printf("Please enter your second number: ");
 scanf("%d",%c);
 printf("Enter your operation");
 scanf("%c",&b);
 if (b == 'a')
 {
     d = a + c;
     printf("The answer is: %d",d);
 }
}
```

When i compile the code this is the error/warnings i get:

```
D:...|4|warning: return type defaults to 'int'|
D:...||In function 'main':|
D:...|10|error: expected expression before '%' token|
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Declare `main()` as `int main(void)` and return 0 from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `%` to a `&` in the `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d", &c);
            ^
```

Also, instead of `main` you want `int main` and you probably should return something at the end.

Comment: Returning something from main is not mandatory since C99. If the end of the main is reached without a return, 0 will be returned. See C99 5.1.2.2.3: `[...] reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0.`

Comment: I do it always too :). Just wanted to clarify

Answer (score 1):

use the & operator instead of % operator.The & operator is used to access the address of a particular variable hence also known as address-of operator.For more details visit:
https://www.techopedia.com/definition/25580/address-of-operator--c

Answer (score 1):

Compare these two lines, and you tell us what the difference is:

```
scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%d",%c);
```